# How to search query in Pinterest using Pinterest V1 API endpoints?

Tags: api, web-scraping, pinterest

I am trying to search some query in Pinterest and fetch the results according to that query using Pinterest V1 API endpoints.  I look at the Pinterest official documentation (https://developers.pinterest.com/docs/getting-started/introduction/) but does not find  any endpoints about the search query.

I only find these (https://gist.github.com/iwek/7549309) from Github gist but it does not works for V1 endpoints.

If anyone knows how to send get request to fetch the results of search query using Pinterest V1 API endpoints , please free to inform me.